# Flask jinja variable breaking css

Tags: python, html, css, flask, jinja2

I am working on a flask application, and am passing a variable back into the rendered html with this block of code:

```
@app.route('/profile')
@login_required
def profile():
    return render_template('profile.html', key = db.get_user_token(session['email']))
```

I want to use this passed key to render the key to the user on the template but it breaks the page when loading. Here are two images to show with the jinja template and without as well as the associated code.

With:

```
<section class="bg-primary text-white mb-0">
        <div class="container-body">
        <h3 class="text-center text-uppercase text-white mb-0">API Key</h1>
            <hr width="50%">
            <div>
                <div class="mb-0 text-center text-white">
                <p id="key">{{key}}</p>
                </div>
                </div>
                <div class="text-center mt-4">
                    <a class="clickable btn btn-xl btn-outline-light" onclick="newKey();">Generate</a>
                </div>
            </div>
    </section>
```

Image of the output:
[with](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CRERH.png)

Without:

```
<section class="bg-primary text-white mb-0">
        <div class="container-body">
        <h3 class="text-center text-uppercase text-white mb-0">API Key</h1>
            <hr width="50%">
            <div>
                <div class="mb-0 text-center text-white">
                <p id="key">This is a bunch of text to show that it is not working when given a variable</p>
                </div>
                </div>
                <div class="text-center mt-4">
                    <a class="clickable btn btn-xl btn-outline-light" onclick="newKey();">Generate</a>
                </div>
            </div>
    </section>
```

Image of the output:
[Without](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g5d9b.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably because the example without is not a single word and it can break to a new line. But with a single word you have to assign some css for the word to break to the new line when it exceeds the width of the container.

Add the code below to your css file and assign the class `.dont-break-out` to `p#key`:

```css
.dont-break-out {

  /* These are technically the same, but use both */
  overflow-wrap: break-word;
  word-wrap: break-word;

  -ms-word-break: break-all;
  /* Instead use this non-standard one: */
  word-break: break-word;

  /* Adds a hyphen where the word breaks, if supported (No Blink) */
  -ms-hyphens: auto;
  -moz-hyphens: auto;
  -webkit-hyphens: auto;
  hyphens: auto;

}
```

Comment: This worked, not sure why it wasen't before thank you!